# Python script to grep fields from text file and writing output in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, scripting, python-2.6

I am writing one python script. Need your help in correcting my script in python 3.x or python 2.6

For each input file need sperate output file in another directory
we have multiple input file with name suppose(1.1.1.2.txt, 1.1.1.3.txt) with kind of same set of data separated by blank line
Need to grep below line from input file(which is text file)
and keep "ave rate from user(bps)" as column heading and "17104773" as its value in row and similarly "ave rate to user(bps)" in another column with heading and "247272821" its value in row in another CSV FILE.

```
session: 43  ave rate from user(bps) : 17104773      ave rate to user(bps)   : 247272821
```

Input file : after running command

```
show sub data-rate smgr-instance 43
```

need to grep and put 43 in output file first column. This 43 is dynamic value

```
[local]AM-SI-SP-01# show sub data-rate smgr-instance 43
Thursday July 1 17:10:45 IST 
Total Subscribers       : 2978
Active                  : 2978          Dormant                 : 0
peak rate from user(bps): n/a*          peak rate to user(bps)  : n/a*
ave rate from user(bps) : 17104773      ave rate to user(bps)   : 247272821
sust rate from user(bps): 16999794      sust rate to user(bps)  : 246777077
peak rate from user(pps): n/a*          peak rate to user(pps)  : n/a*
ave rate from user(pps) : 13117         ave rate to user(pps)   : 27879
sust rate from user(pps): 13233         sust rate to user(pps)  : 27976

[local]AM-SI-SP-01# show sub data-rate smgr-instance 45
Thursday July 1 17:10:45 IST 
Total Subscribers       : 2978
Active                  : 2978          Dormant                 : 0
peak rate from user(bps): n/a*          peak rate to user(bps)  : n/a*
ave rate from user(bps) : 17104234      ave rate to user(bps)   : 24728978
sust rate from user(bps): 16999794      sust rate to user(bps)  : 246777077
peak rate from user(pps): n/a*          peak rate to user(pps)  : n/a*
ave rate from user(pps) : 13117         ave rate to user(pps)   : 27879
sust rate from user(pps): 13233         sust rate to user(pps)  : 27976
```

My code :

```
import os
import csv
import re
from io import BytesIO

def parseFile(somefile):

    data = dict()
    with open(somefile, 'r') as f :

        lines=f.read()
        sub="ave rate from user(bps)"
        if (lines.find(sub))==-1:
            print ("nothing")
        else:
            splitted = lines.split(':')
            data["Hostname"] = splitted[1]
            print (data)



        #print("mylines",lines)
        for line in lines:


            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            print ("line",line)
            #print (lines)
            #print (type(line))


            if (lines.startswith(sub)):
                print ("nothing")

            #continue;
            else:



                print (data)
        #return data
    #print (data)

parseFile("C:\\Users\\ajachaud\Desktop\\scripts\\abc\\fileName.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputsDirectory = "C:/Users/ajachaud/Desktop/scripts"
    path = os.path.abspath(inputsDirectory)
    fileList = ["{}/{}".format(path,x) for x in os.listdir(inputsDirectory)]
   # print(fileList)

    # Load Each File and Build Dictionary
    csvRows = []
    for file in fileList:
        newRow = parseFile(file)
        csvRows.append(newRow)

   # print(csvRows)

    # Output CSV using dictionaries for each file
    outputFile = "output.csv"
    with open(outputFile, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ["Hostname",
                      "loopback"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for row in csvRows:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Expected output in csv file :

```
session,ave rate from user(bps),ave rate to user(bps)
   43    17104773            247272821
   45    17104234            24728978
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import csv


with open("infile.txt") as infile, open("outfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
    data = infile.read()     #Read infile content
    ave_rate_from_user = re.search(r"ave rate from user\(bps\)\s*:\s*(\d+)\b", data)     #Search for `ave rate from user`
    if ave_rate_from_user:
        ave_rate_from_user = ave_rate_from_user.group(1)
    ave_rate_to_user = re.search(r"ave rate to user\(bps\)\s*:\s*(\d+)\b", data)  #Search for `ave rate to user`
    if ave_rate_to_user:
        ave_rate_to_user = ave_rate_to_user.group(1)

    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(["ave rate from user(bps)", "ave rate to user(bps)"])  #Write Header
    writer.writerow([ave_rate_from_user, ave_rate_to_user])    #Write Content
```

- Should work with both version of python mentioned in the question.

Comment: I would not hardcode the strings as by the input file provided it seems he needs it for more than those two. I would use a general expresion that captures any text before the `": "` (note the space) and anything after it until an space is found. I would then trim the first part to get the string properly formatted. After that I would continue doing it for the line until no `": "` is found.

Comment: @Adirio from OP's question ..they just need the two values....and it is also mention in sample code `sub="ave rate from user(bps)"`

Comment: @Rakesh..the above input data is coming after running this command "show sub data-rate smgr-instance 43". Now if i want to grep 43 from this command and display in our output file.. only the numeric value will change in this command..how can we achieve this to get output like below  or output like above that i have edited now...                                   
                   session,ave rate from user(bps),ave rate to user(bps)
                       43      17104773                      247272821